# Understanding the forces on a simple model

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A light elastic string AB has natural length $1.25m$ and modulus of elasticity $24.5N$. Another light string CD has natural length $1.25m$ and modulus of elasticity $26.95N$.

The two strings AB and CD are joined together with B attached to C forming a string AD whose end A is fixed to a horizontal ceiling. A particle of mass 5kg is attached to the free end of the string at D and hangs in equilibrium, without touching the ground.
Determine the length AD.

[image: Model]

I'm a bit unsure as to how the forces act. In the worked solution to the question, the tensions in both the strings are the same, $5g$. Why? Is it because the only forces acting on the ball are weight and tension, and they must be equal as the ball is in equilibrium? I can understand that, but I don't really understand why the tension in the second (top) string is the same as that in the bottom. I also don't understand what R is in reaction to? (see diagram)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tension in each string is $5g$ N because it has to support the particle's weight.  The particle has that force pulling downward because of gravity, so has to have an upward force to balance it.  The support is providing an upward force of $5g$ N to counteract the force at $R$.  If the strings had mass the tension would be increasing as you go up because each bit of string would have to support the particle plus the weight of string below it.